# Testing/Development Environment on local server

Tags: best-practice, development, testing, staging

I need to create a local development environment and struggling a little with the setup. I want to replicate my live server as close as I possibly can. I hope I'm posting this question in a right place...

I want to install **Magento ver 2.1.8**, running **MySQL 5.6**, **PHP 7.0** with **NginX** and **Debian**.

Now, it would be more than one person which will be working on the development sites, therefore, it will have to stored on our local server.

We are working on Windows 10 Pro machines.

I had a look at tools such as **VirtualBox**, **Vagrant** and **Docker** but reading about them got me even more confused. Could anyone help me or direct me a little?

I had a brief look at the **LAMP** stack too. Could you recommend the best way to go for my situation?

Do I have to use these tools in combination with each other?

Do I have to install the software on each computer or on local server?

Answer (score -1):

Github or Bitbucket are popular tools for working on sharing networks. It will merge your website with multiple localhosts and multiple developers can pull their changes on the website using this tool. You can also see what changes done by which developer.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: That sounds good. How do I set the environment on the local server tho?

Comment: Here is documentation link. You can also find links on google, there are so many documentations available for both tools.
https://github.com/features

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-documentation-776639749.html

Comment: That's great but how to I set an actual Magento 2 testing environment on local machine?

Comment: What is the operating system of your local environment ? If it is windows, you have to setup the environment with virtual box as your live environment is in Debian OS. Developers can connect to the virtual box through bridge network using static IP and access it like a server. Assuming that all machines are connected in same LAN. Sorry if more technical terms are involved. Let us know if you need more information or it is enough to get a clear idea on the approach.

Comment: That's correct, all the machines are using Windows 10 pro. All the machines are connected using the same LAN. I will google how to create a virtual box using bridge network, if I will still struggle, I will let you know! Thank you for your response and directing me!